# Preprocessing/precompiling - replace variable by constant

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor, metaprogramming, precompile

I'm working on a function that takes a well known range of arguments, but I don't want to write many different functions for each case. Is there a way to define let's say a "pattern" of function and make the precompiler generate functions based on this pattern?

Example. I have following function:

```
int addition_in_range_of_10 (int a, int b) {    return a+b; }
```

I want to generate following functions:

```
int addition_in_range_of_10_1_1 () {
    return 2;
}

int addition_in_range_of_10_1_2 () {
    return 3;
}

int addition_in_range_of_10_1_3 () {
    return 4;
}

...

int addition_in_range_of_10_10_10 () {
    return 20;
}
```

I want run these functions using pointer to function:

```
int (*funp)();
if(...) {
    funp = addition_in_range_of_10_1_3;
}
funp();
```

Right now I wrote my own app that do from below template functions enumerated above but it is not comfortable to copy code to my app and then result to cpp file and then compile. I want to have it automated.

```
//{A=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10;B=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
int addition_in_range_of_10_{A}_{B} () {
    return {A}+{B};
}
```

Here is my question. Is there any preprocessing library, mechanism, or something what could do it automatically?

I just want to remove variables from code because of performance. Those functions are a lot of more complicated and works a lot better if have constants instead of variables, and because those variables uses only some well known values I would like to change them to constants instead of variables.

Comment: It looks like you want to create a lookup table.

Comment: No offence, but don't you trust your compiler to multiply correctly? :)

Comment: I assume this is a contrived example just to illustrate the kind of mechanism you're looking for.  The problem is, it's **so** contrived that it's difficult to suggest anything sensible here.  What's the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I agree with @mah. 
What you appear to be attempting would be much easier if you created a lookup table.  It doesn't look like a problem you should be solving with dozens of functions.

Comment: To be more clear, a lookup table could be used not only for storing pre-computed additions of values, but also to map functions to arguments.

Comment: Guys it's only example. I just want to remove variables from code because of performance. Those functions are a lot of more complicated and works a lot better if have constants instead of variables, and because those variables uses only some well known values I would like to change them to constants instead of variables.

Comment: @nosbor: You're saying that rather than doing `expensiveFunction(a, b)`, you want to do `lookupTableOfPrecomputedResults[a][b]`?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth No! Results are not computed. That was only example. don't look for solution of computing addition. Just want to replace variables by constants. This is problem my problem.

Comment: @nosbor: Those are equivalent problems, though.  If you have `a=5` and `b=7` at runtime, you cannot call `expensiveFunction_5_7()` without a lookup-table mechanism.

Comment: @nosbor function pointers are going to be A LOT slower than just a const lookup array or a constexpr function.

Comment: What about using template..?

Comment: Do you want C or C++? The answer you will get can differ significantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any special tools you can do this:

```
#define MYADD(A,B) \
    int addition_in_range_of_10_##A##_##B () { \
        return A+B; \
    }

#define MYADD2(A) \
    MYADD(A,1) \
    MYADD(A,2) \
    ...
    MYADD(A,10)

MYADD2(1)
MYADD2(2)
...
MYADD2(10)
```

---

But [boost preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) can help you to make this more compact. Have a look at `BOOST_PP_LOCAL_ITERATE`.

Comment: I think you are missing a `#define ` behind that `MYADD2` thing, unless I am the one missing something.

Answer (score 3):

for C++

```
#include <iostream>

template <int A, int B>
int addition_in_range_of_10(void){
    return A + B;
}

int main(){
    int (*funp)();
    if(1) {
        funp = addition_in_range_of_10<1,3>;
    }
    std::cout << funp() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```